Power BI Sorting stacked columns
I have seen this answered in posts from a few years ago but the interface has changed since and I can't figure it out.
I have a list if items within several processes that have "high", "medium", and "low" ratings. I need to create a stacked column chart with this information, and it would be easiest to read if "high" were at the top of the stack and "low" were at the bottom. Currently, however, the order from top to bottom defaults to "medium" at the top, "low" in the middle, and "high" at the bottom. is there a way to reorganize this in the 2024 version of Power BI?


you can create a dim table. click the rating column and sort by sort column

you link this table to your fact table and when you display the visual use the rating column from the new table.


Perfect! Thank you so much! For anyone who is stupid like me, the parts of this solution I had to figure out is once you create the DIN table (easiest to use "Enter Data" button in the Home tab). Then create the DIN table numbered however you want, then go back to the original table you are using AND CREATE A NEW COLUMN! The formula I used in the formula bar is "1 [sort order column] = related('sort order table'[Order Column]). Then select the column to be sorted, and under Column tools tab in the ribbon, select "sort by column" and chose the new column. WOO HOO
